# How to remove duplicate key from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My csv file

```
student,gender,id

jimmy,male,001
joe,male,002
joe,male,002
hugo,female,003
```

My code

```
with open('student.csv', 'r') as csv_file, open('new_student.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',)

    list_1 = list(csv_reader)

    for line in list_1:

        data = [['jimmy', 'male', '001'], ['joe', 'male', '002'],['joe', 'male', '002'],['hugo', 'female', '003']]

        set(data)
```

The set method will hit `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Same error if I try something like `data= line(dict.fromkeys(data))`

Comment: `set(map(tuple, data))` ?

Comment: is the `id` unique?

Comment: BTW, move the `data = ...` line outside of the loop body. You do not want it to be defined four times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutable types (such as lists) cannot be used as keys in sets and dictionaries. Convert the inner lists to *tuples*, which are immutable:

```
>>> set(map(tuple, data))
{('jimmy', 'male', '001'), ('hugo', 'female', '003'), ('joe', 'male', '002')}
```

---

`map(tuple, data)` is equivalent to:

- `tuple(d) for d in data` in Python 3.x
- `[tuple(d) for d in data]` in Python 2.x – would be more efficient to use `itertools.imap` here

Comment: can you elaborate on your solution please, what `map(tuple,data))` exactly do?

Comment: oh, you first convert items to tuples, then use `set` on them since they are hash-able. is that correct?

Comment: @MagedSaeed everything in Python is hashable, but for them to be used in sets / dicts they also have to be **immutable** (values cannot change).